# How to get installed unbuffer on centos?

Tags: centos, yum, expect

```
$ unbuffer
-bash: unbuffer: command not found
```

Centos 7.x

How to install it by using `yum`?

`yum install unbuffer` doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/expect-5.45-14.el7_1.x86_64.rpm.html

`unbuffer` is a part of `expect` package.

```
yum install expect -y
```